# What is better approach to play mp3/wav and change tempo(audio speed) Android?

Tags: android

I have tried

```
1) MediaPlayer(it Doesnt support speed change).
2) SoundPool (play only small audio files)
3) AudioTrack (tried with JLayer- there is delay. decoder is slow).
4) Sonic NDK master - unable to play mp3 audio files
```

what would be better to use? any idea or suggestions? How should i approach?

Comment: NB: MediaPlayer does support audio speed on API23+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things have changed since the last answer, so I'll try provide some new info:

**TL;DR:** ExoPlayer is the best solution. It's using Sonic and easier to compile.

**MediaPlayer**

- Pros: Part of android API, no need to add libraries, fastest solution
- Cons: Speed and pitch works only with API 23 and above

How to change speed:

```
mediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(new PlaybackParams().setSpeed(1.5f));
```

**Sonic NDK**

- Pros: Works with old API, good quality
- Cons: Works with PCM so MP3 decoder needed, C compilation complicates your project and build process

But... The cons are not that bad.

The PCM thing is actually not a problem anymore because Android has MediaCodec API, so you don't need external MP3 decoders.

I have a project on github that uses Sonic with Android's deocder and configured for Android Studio (the original project is Eclipse):
https://github.com/mega-arbuz/android-mp3-sonic-ndk

You can also avoid compiling C code and use the JAVA implementation for Sonic:
https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic/blob/master/Sonic.java

**ExoPlayer**

- Pros: Uses Sonic for speed/pitch/rate, good quality, Works with API 16,  supported by Google
- Cons: Not a part of SDK like MediaPlayer, a bit large (6k methods, 1MB), usage is more complicated than MediaPlayer

[Tutorial for creating Activity with ExoPlayer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#0)

[Documentation and samples](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer)

After you're done with the tutorial, the speed change is simple:

```
player.setPlaybackParameters(new PlaybackParameters(1.5f, 1.0f));
```

---

A few years ago, Sonic with a decoder was the best solution, but now ExoPlayer is the best. It supports old enough API, uses Sonic, has the same speech quality and doesn't require complicated compilation and project setup.

Comment: definitely a lot has been changed since my question. Its about 5 year old. So I accept your answer, as it seems to provide the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

Just a bit of information from my experience. OpenSL ES is another option. It is a C++ library so you will need to use the Android NDK. I could not get this method working as for some reason i kept getting an error returned which stated that the interface was unsupported even though it says in the documentation that it is http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/opensles/ .

Another option is use http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/ which is a great C++ library that can be used with the android NDK and has great support from the developer Olli.

In terms of the other methods you have mentioned:

- MediaPlayer simply will not work
- Soundpool is very limited due to it only working with small files
- AudioTrack looks to be the best option but only plays PCM files so conversion of MP3 files may be required.